# Security assesment on homemade bridge between internal server and DMZ

Tags: c#, security, network-programming, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble really assessing whether or not I'm exposing our internal servers in a very unsecure and obvious way.

I have 2 domains, one internal and one external (dmz) on the firewall. I need information from the internal, and we don't want to start a migration thing, or open up ports directly to the internal server. I'm unable to connect from DMZ to internal, but the other way works fine.

I created a web api service on the dmz, which has a static `TcpListener`, and accepts only one connection.

I then created a simple console application on the internal server, connecting to this web api `TcpListener`. It holds on to the connection, and I'm able to send commands via rest-api calls to the dmz server, and send back Json data from the internal server, thus obtaining the bilateral connection I needed.

What I'm wondering is, whether this will pose a serious threat to our security? I don't know enough about network security to be able to say, but the `TcpListener` only has that one connection, and it's only open long enough for me to occupy this connection.

Can anyone give me a clue as to how (in)secure this solution is?

Answer (score 0):

The server is in DMZ, so anyone can connect to your `TcpListener`. A port scan will reveal this listening socket. You need to apply authentication (client certificate / IP whitelist / basic / digest / ...).

Comment: Okay, but connecting to the TcpListener is one thing. Is it possible for anyone to actually use this socket for anything other than what I expose in my api? And keep in mind, it's not really a problem if they connect to the TcpListener in the DMZ - the issue is more if they would be able to use the connection to the internal server (which is a client) after it's been established?

Comment: Can a hacker use your connection to Stack Overflow to attack your pc?

Comment: Well, honestly, I know it's probably being paranoid. But considering my lack of network knowledge and sub-par leet hacker skillz, I honestly wasn't sure if there were some basic measures I should make sure was in place. Measures that browsers/servers might employ by default.

Comment: Well anyway no, an connection initiated from machine A to machine B cannot be intercepted by machine C unless the latter is in the same (intermediate) network as either A or B.